# How to read Outlook nickname list file (.NK2)?

Tags: outlook, pst

Anyone know how to read Outlook nickname list file (.NK2)? Any document on how its format is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found this while searching: [debunk2](http://code.google.com/p/debunk2/wiki/fileformat).